# Cannot print value of a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow. I have seen tutorials and some other questions here. However, there is something wrong and I don't understand why (I am still not exactly sure about how tf works).

I have this code (I have tried few other options, but the result was always the same):

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["exoTrain.csv"])
features, label = read_from_file(filename_queue) 
testSess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
testSess.run(init)
print(testSess.run(features))
testSess.close()
```

where `features` is a `tf.stack`: `Tensor("stack:0", shape=(3197,), dtype=float32)`

This code does not print anything. And, actually, it just gets stuck, and I have to manually stop it.

Why it is not terminating properly and why it is not printing?

Comment: How long did you wait? It can take quite a while until the queue has been filled with enough elements before it starts yielding elements.

Comment: I actually left it in the background for pretty long time, but nothing ever changed.

Comment: Never mind, you forget to start the queue runners: `tf.train.start_queue_runners()`